# Hls stream -> Nginx (free) -> Rtsp stream

Tags: nginx, stream, rtsp, http-live-streaming

Is that even possible? I would like to stream a 4K Stereo video and although VLC seems to work i want a more stable option like NGINX.

Comment: Nginx is not intended for that. Why not use FFmpeg?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Can you give an example? I want actually to broadcast a (live) 4K Stereo video. VLC acting as a server bu i am not confident that it will help when i will have 100 users. FFMPEG needs a server right? ( "FFmpeg can basically stream through one of two ways: It either streams to a some "other server", which re-streams for it to multiple clients, or it can stream via UDP/TCP directly to some single destination receiver, or alternatively directly to a multicast destination. " ) Thank you!

Comment: You need to setup ffserver. Here is a sample configuration (https://www.ffmpeg.org/sample.html). Start with that and adjust the source to your hls source, google has tons of examples.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis thank you very much for your answer. According to this http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ffserver ffserver has stopped so i tried to avoid it. Especially for my case (restream HLS stream with RTSP over UDP) i thought that it would cause me more trouble than solution. But you really think i can count on ffserver? If not, do you know another solution to suggest? Thank you!

Comment: oh, I was unaware that his has happened. Well, for commercial purposes people usually build something of their own using FFmpeg (ffserver is also simply a server based on FFmpeg), but I am not sure what programming skills you have, so it's hard to advise. But still, at least try to setup ffserver and see where you stop, if you do stop at all.